# I'm not able to include source file stdafx.h

Tags: visual-c++

I just installed visual studio 22 and I'm learning c++ but I keep seeing this error-E1696 cannot open source file "stdafx.h". Why is that so?

I haven't exactly tried anything since I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Are you trying to open a file/project, or is this simply upon opening the IDE? Also, to be clear, it is Visual Studio (Community or Professional) Edition, or V.S. Code?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it a pre-compiled header file, It helps in speeding up the C++ application. Notice the double quotes "" over there that means it is a user added header file generally headers will be in <> and for user added header file #include"location of the header file" stdafx is generally added by the compiler in a default project location and for an empty project the compiler wont create any files at all so you need to add New Item(Header file) with the name of stdafx.h to make the application work for you. Remember this will not speed up the C++ application.

Comment: how is this process done

Comment: Add stdafx.h file in the  project folder structure.